# bold words instead of number in citation call-outs

Tags: citing

I want to cite some references in my article. (I used `\cite{}`.) However, it turns out some bold words instead of citation numbers are produced. Here is my code:

```
\usepackage{url}
\renewcommand{\UrlFont}{\small\tt}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usetikzlibrary{automata,arrows,positioning,calc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{setspace}



\section{Data}
The data were collected from ITTF \cite{ITTF}.

\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{J}
McGarry, T., and Franks, I.M., 
A stochastic approach to predicting competition squash match-play,
\emph{Journal of Sport Sciences}, 1994, 12, 573-584. 

\bibitem{l}
Lames, M.
\emph{Leistungsdiagnostik durch Computersimulation. [Performance diagnosis by computer simulation]}.
Frankfurt/Main: Harri Deutsch, 1991, pp. 7-257. 

\bibitem{ITTF}
International Table Tennis Federation. 
\\\texttt{http://www.ittf.com/}

\end{thebibliography}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SX! Can you turn your snippet into a complete example, so that we can copy-paste and compile it without changing anything? (I don't mean your entire document, but add the `documentclass` and whatever you need from the preamble, if anything, a `document` environment and a `\cite` command or two -- it should be a minimal example.) When I add your code snippet in a minimal example of my own it works as expected, so there's something going on that you're not showing us.

Comment: OP, it looks like you have two accounts. You should get them merged, or log in with the original one, in order to be able to edit your own posts and also interact with the site correctly (make comments down here, accept answers, earn rep and so on and so forth)

Comment: The cause is that you've added the `biblatex` package, which you're not actually using. Remove `\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}`, delete the `.aux` file, and run `pdflatex` again.

Comment: You have two userid with the same nickname "Jessie T", maybe you have used "sign in" instead of "log in" to enter here the second time. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-or-bold-citation-key-instead-of-citation-number

Answer (score 2):

Since you appear to be building the bibliography entirely by hand, there's no point in loading the `biblatex` package. Instead, you should load a citation management package, such as `cite`, that generates numerical citation call-outs. (If you don't want to load the `cite` package, you could load the `natbib` package with the option `numbers`; however, you'll also have to provide a dummy `\bibliographystyle` instruction.) If such a citation management package is loaded, you'll be able to generate multiple citation call-outs -- sorted and compressed, if applicable -- with a single `\cite` command.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
% simplified the preamble to the bare minimum...
\usepackage{url}
\renewcommand{\UrlFont}{\small\tt}
\usepackage{cite} % <--- new
\begin{document}

\section{Data}
The data were collected from ITTF \cite{ITTF}.

\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem{J}
McGarry, T., and Franks, I.M., 
A stochastic approach to predicting competition squash match-play,
\emph{Journal of Sport Sciences}, 1994, 12, 573--584. 

\bibitem{l}
Lames, M.
\emph{Leistungsdiagnostik durch Computersimulation. [Performance diagnosis by computer simulation]}.
Frankfurt/Main: Harri Deutsch, 1991, pp. 7--257. 

\bibitem{ITTF}
International Table Tennis Federation. 
\url{http://www.ittf.com/}
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```